# Creating a "top list" from dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, converters

I have dictionary, something like:

```
x = {"John":15,"Josh":2,"Emily":50,"Joey":12}
```

And I need to create something like this:

> 1. Emily - 50
> 2. John - 15
> 3. Joey - 12
> 4. Josh - 2

What would be the best way to do this? I have already tried to sort the dictionary somehow, but then it converted to list and I wasn't able to get both values (name and number).

Comment: You can use `sorted(x)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With simple sorting by dictionary values:

```
x = {"John":15, "Josh":2, "Emily":50, "Joey":12}

for i, t in enumerate(sorted(x.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True), 1):
    print('{}. {} - {}'.format(i, t[0], t[1]))
```

The output:

```
1. Emily - 50
2. John - 15
3. Joey - 12
4. Josh - 2
```

Comment: Thank you, last question, how to limit it to just top 3?

Comment: @Arbys, welcome, just add `if i == 3: break` as next line after `print` statement

Answer (score 0):

See the answer here: [How do I sort a dictionary by value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613183/how-do-i-sort-a-dictionary-by-value)

In your case, you'll want to reverse sorted_x as you want higher values first, so:

```
import operator


x = {"John":15,"Josh":2,"Emily":50,"Joey":12}
sorted_x = sorted(x.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

An easy way:

```
x = {"John":15,"Josh":2,"Emily":50,"Joey":12}

val = sorted([y for y in x.values()])
name = val[:]
for key in x.keys():
    id = val.index(x[key])
    name[id] = key
```